# javaScript: window.open not displaying background image

Tags: javascript, background-image

Please help me, I have been working on this for hours. I have just started playing with JavaScript.

So I have a button that loads a new browser window, loads background image. As below, no problems.

HTML

```
<script>
        setBackground();
</script>
```

JavaScript

```
function setBackground() {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#000000";
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(bg.jpg)"
}
```

Then I try to load another window on button click but the background image will not work. The window works, I can change the background color no problem, but I can't get the image to load. code below.

```
//load screen on button click
            document.getElementById("startButton").onclick = function() { 
                                                                        load()
                                                                        
                                                                    };


function load() {
    //create the new screen
    newWindow = window.open("", "", "width=1550, height=800");
    newWindow.id = "game";
    newWindow.document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#000000";
    newWindow.document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(bg.jpg)";
    
}
```

The files and images are located in the same folder, I'm using the same image, it works in the first example but not the second.

Please help!!! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @PatrickEvans. I did, i just changed it for the code posted. edit variable so its clearer. thanks

Comment: Any URL calls from window is relative to domain and current URI in address. You are creating window with blank URL. I think that's why bg.jpg request is not working.

Comment: ok. how do I fix it? I have tried getElementById("game").setAttributes but not working ethier. A point in the right direction work be apricated

Comment: You can pass base64 image. Like 
"var xyz = 'data:image/png;base64, base64ImageContent';
newWindow.document.body.style.background = 'url(\'' + xyz + '\')';"

Answer (score 0):

Check this link and click on Run

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GM9IO9Q6SDNL

try this.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body onload="setBackground()" >

    </body>

    <script>
           function setBackground() {
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg)"
        newWindowSetBackgroundload()
    }
    function newWindowSetBackgroundload() {
        //create the new screen
      var newWindow = window.open("", "", "width=1550, height=800");
      //Id use for Uniq thats why its render only one time
    //  newWindow.id = "game";
    //use class for multiple windows genration 
newWindow.class = "game";
        newWindow.document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#000000";
        newWindow.document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg)";
        
    }
    </script>
    </html>
```